# SNR or signal and noise levels in ad-hoc mode

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am using the WiPi dongle which is based on the rt2800usb driver on my Raspberry Pis (running raspbian) in an ad-hoc network, and I can't seem to be able to get any SNR, signal or noise level readings as output from `iwconfig`. The only thing that shows me just the signal level is `iw dev wlan0 station dump`, but is there any way I could get the noise levels as well, or SNR even better?

Also, is it driver/adapter related, or is there any command I am missing which would enable me to get what I am looking for?